# Tracking down non-engine sounds

Tags: suspension, mitsubishi, noise, montero

I have a '01 Montero that has been making a creaking/squeaky type of noise that comes from the rear of vehicle. I have lubed everything there is and have installed new shocks and air bags. Doesn't seem to be stemming from there. NOW, I did have a towing hitch installed and after inspection the "dude" didn't have enough of the proper bolts and two of those are longer and really tight against the underside body. Would these bolts possibly be the culprit of this annoying noise? I imagine I can take them out and see but... Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the brakes?  Welcome to the site.  I worry this question is too broad, and there's not much for us to go on since we can't hear the sound.  When does the sound happen?  Any chance of capturing it?

Comment: Removing the hitch botls may not help if the squeak is coming from the hitch where it rests against the frame, take it somewhere and get it properly mounted.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the noise? i.e. exactly what conditions cause it.